# How to change behavior regarding "Cannot play video" error

Tags: android, streaming, android-videoview

I am trying to play a video via HTTP. It sometimes plays fine, others I get the "Cannot play video" error but can immediately start playing it again. It seems it will display this error on the slightest hiccup, is there anyway to increse the tolerance so it can continue through instead of just dropping the download and popping up the error?

Answer (score 0):

implement a `OnErrorListener` for your application and set `viewview.setOnErrorListener(classhere);` Then you can handle errors the way you want to.